# Bridge a dummy and physical ethernet interface on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, bridge

I'm trying to bridge a dummy interface, dummy0, and a physical interface, eth1. I've used the following commands for creating a bridge, br0, for the two interfaces, but they aren't getting bridged. Any suggestions?

```
ip link add dev dummy0 type dummy  # Create dummy0. eth1 already exists
brctl addbr br0                    # Create bridge br0
brctl addif br0 dummy0             # Add dummy0 to br0
brctl addif br0 eth1               # Add eth1 to br0
ip link set dev dummy0 up
ip link set dev eth1 up
ip link set dev br0 up
```

At this point, any packets received on eth1 from the outside world (since eth1 is a physical port connected to an external device) should get transmitted by dummy0, and vice-versa. That doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 5):

They *are* transmitted, but through the *other end* of the interface. Which, on "dummy" interfaces, is not attached to anything – that's the entire idea of "dummy" interfaces – so the packets go nowhere.

Imagine eth0 as being connected to the OS network stack at the "front" and to the physical Ethernet port at the "back". Packets received from the port are seen by the OS as coming out of eth0, and vice versa, packets that the OS sends through eth0 come out of the physical port.

[image]

A bridge between e.g. eth0 and eth1 would connect all the "front" ends and therefore relay packets between the "back" connections – what's received in through eth0 physical port would be relayed through the bridge and sent back out through eth1 physical port.

Bridging dummy0 works the same way, but because dummy0 has nothing on the "other side", any packets that *are* being sent through dummy0 get discarded – they do not get "reflected" back to the OS (dummy interfaces don't reflect packets in general, and the front of dummy0 is taken over by the bridge anyway).

[image]

So in other words, bridging dummy0 is nearly useless. (The only situations it helps is when you need to make the bridge appear non-empty.) If you want the OS to speak with the bridge, you can already do so without a dummy interface – the br0 interface *itself* is connected to the OS network stack.