# Linux: Simulate two servers via virtual network

Tags: linux, networking

I have the following problem. I want to run a local simulation of two server applications that both open a network socket. These applications normally run separately on embedded Linux devices. A third application is a client that should communicate with both servers.
Since it is not possible to open two sockets on the same interface, I have tried to create three virtual interfaces and connect them with a bridge:

```
sudo ip link add eth10 type dummy
sudo ip link add eth11 type dummy
sudo ip link add eth12 type dummy
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge

sudo ip link set dev eth10 master br0
sudo ip link set dev eth11 master br0
sudo ip link set dev eth12 master br0

sudo ip addr add 192.168.42.42/24 dev eth10
sudo ip addr add 192.168.42.43/24 dev eth11
sudo ip addr add 192.168.42.44/24 dev eth12

sudo ip link set dev eth10 up
sudo ip link set dev eth11 up
sudo ip link set dev eth12 up

sudo ip link set dev br0 up
```

This works so far, I can start all applications and the client can access both servers. However, the servers should also communicate with each other via an IEC61850-GOOSE protocol. But this does not work. It looks as if there is no layer 2 communication via the virtual network - I cannot see the expected packets in Wireshark either.
The client-server communication (IEC61850-MMS) is TCP/IP based and works.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Simulating computers is usually done via virtual machines.

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/a/1745471/1686 or https://superuser.com/a/1781135/1686 explain the situation?

Comment: @harrymc I do not want to simulate computers but applications. I would like to avoid the overhead of a VM, it would be annoying, especially for debugging the applications.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Thanks for the links. It looks like for my purpose the TAPs are actually what I need instead of the dummy interfaces. I'll test whether it works.

Comment: In your case it sounds like you want applications to think they're using regular Ethernet, in which case veth would be a better fit than tap (as programs need a different kind of API to control the "program" end of the tap interface).

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in other posts (https://superuser.com/a/1745471, https://superuser.com/a/1781135), network interfaces do not act as mirrors, they act like pipes – and your problem is that packets sent by software are going in the wrong direction, *away* from the bridge rather than towards the bridge.

[image]

What you need is to make the OS think you've *received* the packet, instead of it being sent. There are two common options:

- If you're writing custom networking tools: You can create `tap` interfaces, which are connected to a process instead of a network (or instead of "nowhere" as is the case for dummy interfaces).

  Programs must use a special API to control the 'tap' interface. When the process sends an Ethernet frame through this API, the OS (and therefore the bridge) will *receive* it through the 'tap' interface, and vice versa. This interface type is very commonly used for VPN software (e.g. OpenVPN or ZeroTier); 'tun' interfaces are the same except without the Ethernet L2 header.

  (Sample code for using a TAP interface: https://git.nullroute.lt/hacks/udptap.git/tree/)
- If you need to run unmodified software: You can create `veth` interfaces, which always come in pairs and act like two ends of a pipe. (Creating a veth0 will automatically bring veth1 into existence, and so on.)

  Your programs can then use one end of a veth-pair to send their Ethernet frames or IP packets in the regular way, and the packets will be "received" through the corresponding other veth interface.

  This is very often used for containers (e.g. Docker); one end of the veth-pair gets moved into the container's network namespace while the other remains visible to the host. (It's indeed very common to bridge the 'host' ends of multiple containers' veths to put them on a "virtual switch".)

  So you can e.g. create three pairs (0-1, 2-3, 4-5), put veth0/veth2/veth4 in your bridge, then have programs talk to each other via veth1/veth3/veth5. The interfaces can be created using standard `ip link add`.

(Other related types are macvtap and macvlan, which *might* be useful in some situations here.)

---

This all assumes your software directly sends raw Ethernet frames and bypasses the Linux TCP/IP stack. For programs that speak regular IP, it's not enough to just have the interfaces – IP communications to a local address are looped back by the OS, even if that address is on a different interface – and you would usually need *namespaces* to isolate each "simulated server" in.

Namespaces are how containers work, but instead of running a whole container you can pick and choose what to isolate; in this case you would only need network namespaces while leaving everything else (filesystem, etc) shared. You can create network namespaces using `ip netns` or the generic tools `unshare` & `nsenter`, and you can move interfaces (e.g. one end of a veth-pair) into namespaces using `ip link set <name> netns <pid>`.